# show some static values in wpf datagrid combobox column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am trying to use a `DataGrid` whose first column is a `ComboxBox`. This `ComboxBox` has a hardcoded static values, possible values are: `Employee, Contractor, Supplier`

How can I show some static values in the `DataGrid` without binding to a `DataSource`.
I am new to WPF so more detailed explanation would help.

Comment: What does you mean when you say "standard grid"?

Comment: where did I say  standard grid?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you mean the wpf toolkit datagrid, you could do it like so:

```
        <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn 
           Header="String Column" 
           SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=RoleProperty}">
           <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
              <CompositeCollection>
                 <system:String>Employee</system:String>
                 <system:String>Contractor</system:String>
                 <system:String>Supplier</system:String>
              </CompositeCollection>
           </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
        </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

in this the items displayed have a property called RoleProperty. you would also need an xnl namespace defintion at the top of your xaml (with the rest of them like:

```
   xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

to let you include the system namespace. (to get access to the Strings)

Comment: `<x:Array>` would be significantly more efficient than `<CompositeCollection>`, and more readable too - most people don't know what a `CompositeCollection` is, let alone that it can be used this way.  An array is a much cleaner choice in my opinion.

Comment: excellent idea ray. i was coding too fast using intellisense and composite collection came up first.

Comment: gave it a go (and in the two minutes or so i tried) and couldnt get array instantiated in xaml, said something about no public constructor

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a standard ComboBox with your static values as ComboBoxItems like so:

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBoxItem>Employee</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>Contractor</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>Supplier</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```